# Properly redirecting a subdomain to subdirectory invisibly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know similar things have been asked before, but none of the solutions I've found have seemed to work out. I'm by far an expert when it comes to mod_rewrite and it's ilk, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

I am trying to invisibly redirect subdomains to an `index.php` file in a subdirectory; this file takes the value of the subdomain as part of the query string, which is working fine.

The problem I'm having is that now *everything* in this subdirectory is being redirected to the `index.php` file, which I don't want to happen.

This is what I have thus far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# User dashboards
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ app/index.php?user=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

What I'm looking for is a situation where `http://subdomain.example.com/` will lead to `/app/index.php?user=subdomain`, but `http://subdomain.example.com/assets/stylesheet.css` will go to `/app/assets/stylesheet.css`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood well your example, you can do it this way:

1. redirects example.com to www.example.com to avoid having "empty" subdomain
2. internally rewrites every root subdomains (except www) to /app/index.php?user=subdomain
3. internally rewrites other things with "app" prefix

Which is represented by this code

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirects example.com to www.example.com to avoid having "empty" subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# internally rewrites every root subdomains (except www) to /app/index.php?user=subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /app/index.php?user=%1 [L,NC,QSA]

# internally rewrites other things with "app" prefix
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !app/
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /app/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

---

EDIT: as you asked in below comments, here is how to manage also `www` subdomain

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirects example.com to www.example.com to avoid having "empty" subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# internally redirects www subdomain root to /site/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /site/index.php [L]

# internally rewrites every other root subdomains to /app/index.php?user=subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /app/index.php?user=%1 [L,NC,QSA]

# internally rewrites other things with "app" prefix
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !app/
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /app/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: That's solved my problem! 

Is it possible to direct the www. subdomain to a different directory too?

Comment: Yes. What should be the rule for www subdomain ?

Comment: Can it be (similarly invisibly) redirected towards something like `/site`?

Comment: Also, correction, the subdomain variable doesn't seem to be added to the query string anymore.

Comment: Can you give me the complete path for www subdomain (except if it is `/site` only) ? What do you mean by `the subdomain variable doesn't seem to be added to the query string anymore` ? Do you have an example url when it is not working ?

Comment: As other subdomains are going to `/app/index.php`, is it possible to get the www. subdomain to `/site/index.php`?

Comment: Also don't worry about the query string. The edit you made a few minutes ago seems to have rectified that.

Comment: I think that's everything! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let add second rule to redirect assets to app/assets:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ app/index.php?user=%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ app/assets/$1 [L,QSA]
```

or load all css/js/images directly from app:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$ app/$0 [NC, QSA]
RewriteRule ^.*$ app/index.php?user=%1 [L,QSA]
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, I haven't tested it before, so there is working example:

```
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ app/assets/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^app/assets/ app/index.php?user=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry, the first example doesn't seem to have changed anything, and the second is giving me a 500 Internal Server Error message.